# rails server won't run WEBrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a total newbie, trying to follow a Rails tutorial and have successfully run the install routine from http://railsinstaller.org/

I have also installed mysql

I have used the command>
rails new simple_cms -d mysql

this appeared to run successfully

when I run 
rails server

this is the output below - doesn't seem to bootup WEBrick on port 3000

Many thanks

===============

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in
>   `require':
>   dlopen(/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle,
>   9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
>
>   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>   Reason: image not found -
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>     from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in`
>   '    from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in
>   `require'     from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`
>   block (2 levels) in require'     from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in
>   `each'    from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`
>   block in require'    from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in
>   `each'    from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/amelrose/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in`'  from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in
>   `require'     from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in`
>   block in '   from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in
>   `tap'     from
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`
>   '    from script/rails:6:in `require'    from
>   script/rails:6:in`'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Because on Mac OS X, mysql usually installs in `/usr/local/mysql`, you will need to manually set the path to the `libmysqlclient` in `/usr/lib`.

Run this in a terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```